# Euler quotients modulo $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences

For odd integer $n$, define the Euler quotient modulo $n$ to be $a(n)$:

$$ a(n)=\frac{(2^{\phi(n)}-1) \bmod n^2}{n}=\frac{2^{\phi(n)}-1}{n} \bmod n$$

$a(n)=0$ for [OEIS sequence Wieferich numbers](https://oeis.org/A077816)

**Conjecture 1** If a Wieferich prime $p$ divides $n$, then $p$ divides $a(n)$
and in addition $\gcd(n,a(n))>1$.

**Conjecture 2** For $n$ Mersenne number $M_m=2^m-1$ we have
$a(2^m-1)= \phi(2^m-1)/m$.

This holds for $m$ up to 200.

**Conjecture 3** If a Wieferich prime $p$ divides $M_m$, then
$p$ divides $ \phi(2^m-1)/m$.

This holds for $p=1093$.

Which of the conjectures are true?

> Question1 Does these conjectures and the answer(s) contribute new results about Wieferich primes?

Answer (score 6):

Conjecture 1. Assume that $p$ is a Wiefrich prime, that is, $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$. Denote $n=p^km$ where $p$ does not divide $m$. By [lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma), $p^{1+k}$ divides $2^{(p-1)p^{k-1}\varphi(m)}-1=2^{\varphi(n)}-1$, thus $p$ divides $a(n)$.

Conjecture 2. Denote $2^m-1=t$. We should prove that $(2^{\varphi(t)}-1)/t\equiv \varphi(t)/m\pmod {t}$. Denote $\varphi(t)=mk$. Then $(2^{\varphi(t)}-1)/t=(2^{mk}-1)/(2^m-1)=(1+2^m+\ldots+2^{m(k-1)})\equiv k\pmod{t}$ as needed.

Conjecture 3. Assume that $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$ and $p$ divides $2^m-1$. Let $s$ denote the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $p$. Then $p-1=sr$ for integer $r$, and $p^2$ divides $2^s-1$ (by lifting the exponent lemma, for example). Next, if $p$ divides $2^m-1$, then $s$ divides $m$, write $m=sp^AB$ where $p$ does not divide $B$. Then $2^m-1$ is divisible by $p^{A+2}$ by lifting the exponent lemma, therefore $p^{A+1}$ divides $\varphi(2^m-1)$, that yields the result.

Comment: You don't appear to address the division by $n$ and the denominator of $a(n)$. Is this typo?

Comment: $n$ has $p$ in power $k$, numerator has $p$ in power at least $k+1$

Comment: Does these conjectures contribute new results about Wieferich primes? If there are are only finitely many non-Wieferich primes, for all n we have gcd(n,a(n)) very large.

Comment: This is a very short proof that Mersenne number, not necessary prime can't be Wieferich number because the totient doesn't vanish.