# Non-Wieferich primes with Euler quotient modulo $p$ two and alternating harmonic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences, oeis

Let $b(n)$ denote the [Euler quotient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394253/euler-quotients-modulo-n) modulo $n$.

In OEIS we have [A128465 Numbers k such that k divides the numerator of alternating Harmonic number H'((k+1)/2)](https://oeis.org/A128465)

For $n>1$ we have $b(A128465(n))=2$.

Also all primes up to $10^8$ with $b(n)=2$ are in the sequence.

> Q1 Is this relation between the sequence and Euler quotients true?

There are too few terms for experimental evidence.

Comment: The "Euler quotient" $b(n)$ is $(2^{\phi(n)}-1)/n$, reduced modulo $n$. The alternating harmonic number $H'(m)$ is $\sum_1^m(-1)^{k+1}/k$.

Comment: Would you be willing to change "Euler quotient modulo $p$ two" to "Euler quotient $2$ modulo $p$"?  It took me forever to parse the title, and I'm still not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 4):

While no composite terms of A128465 are known, here is a proof that an odd prime $p$ belongs to A128465 if and only if $b(p)\equiv 2(-1)^{\tfrac{p+1}2}\pmod{p}$.

First notice that for an odd prime $p$, $b(p)$ equals [Fermat quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient) $q_p(2)$ modulo $p$.

Then,
$$H'(\tfrac{p+1}2)=\sum_{k=1}^{\tfrac{p+1}2} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\equiv 2(-1)^\tfrac{p-1}2-\frac12 H(\tfrac{p-1}2)\pmod{p}.$$

It follows that an odd prime $p$ belongs to A128465 if and only if
$$H(\tfrac{p-1}2) \equiv 4(-1)^\tfrac{p-1}2 \pmod{p}.$$
On the other hand, the formula (45) in [Lehmer (1938)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968791) states:
$$H(\tfrac{p-1}2) \equiv -2q_p(2) + pq_p(2)^2\pmod{p^2}.$$

That is, an odd prime $p$ belongs to A128465 if and only if
$$q_p(2)\equiv 2(-1)^\tfrac{p+1}2 \pmod{p}.$$
QED

Comment: Thanks. Could there be generalization for divisibility and fixed Fermat quotient?

Comment: @joro: Some generalizations are given in the cited Lehmer's paper.